# How can I combine vuejs v-for with Unslider

Tags: vue.js, unslider

Recently, I've encountered a problem when trying to combine vuejs's v-for wih [Unslider](http://unslider.com/)

My Html

```
  <div class="my-slider" >
       <ul>
          <li>
              <div class="show-box" v-for="item in soloColImgs" track-by="$index">
              <img v-bind:src="item.imgUrl"/>
              <a v-bind:href="item.itemUrl" target="_blank"></a>
              </div>
          </li>
       </ul>
  </div>
```

My Js for unslider

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.my-slider').unslider({
        autoplay:true
    });
});
```

v-for and unslider works well when they are seperated. But I want to combine them. It would be greatful if anyone can help me out of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap unslider plugin as vue component and use it.

```
//code using the un-slider component
<div class="browser">
  <un-slider>
    <ul>
           <li v-for="i in 6"> {{ i }} is an item </li>
      </ul>
  </un-slider>  
</div>

//defining template for unslider component
<template id="unslider-template">
<div class="my-slider" v-el:slider>
  <slot></slot>
</div>
</template>


//initialize vue
new Vue({
    el:".browser",
  components:{

   // as it is a simple component, I have written the code here.
   // you should not write it here.
   UnSlider: {
    template:"#unslider-template",
    ready: function(){
     jQuery(this.$els.slider).unslider();     
    }
   },
  }
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/efbpgct7/1/)

PS: I am unable to get css working. No idea why it is not working.